# Case statement with 'not like' possible?

Tags: t-sql

I’m looking to case all bacheloreatte degrees that are not BA’s or BS’s seperately (BSAST for example).   I tried a nested case statement, but as I’m relatively new to t-sql I'm not sure if it was my syntax or that it’s not possible.  Note that this is in a select statement.

```
SELECT
t2.ID,
t2.ACAD_PROGRAM,
'092013' AS T01,
'274842' AS T02,
REPLACE(p.SSN,'-','') AS T03,
'5' AS T04,
ap.ACPG_CIP AS T05,
CASE(t2.ACAD_PROGRAM)
  WHEN 'BA%' THEN '1'
  WHEN 'BS' THEN '2'
  ELSE (CASE
          WHEN t4.STP_DEGREE LIKE 'BA%'
          THEN '1' END)
END AS T06
```

Answer (score 4):

**[CASE has two formats](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)**, to be able to use with `LIKE operator`, your *first CASE* should be a `Searched Case`:

```
SELECT t2.ID, t2.ACAD_PROGRAM, '092013' AS T01, '274842' AS T02, 
       REPLACE(p.SSN,'-','') AS T03, '5' AS T04, ap.ACPG_CIP AS T05, 
       CASE WHEN t2.ACAD_PROGRAM LIKE 'BA%' THEN '1' 
            WHEN t2.ACAD_PROGRAM = 'BS' THEN '2' 
       ELSE 
           CASE WHEN t4.STP_DEGREE LIKE 'BA%' THEN '1' END
       END AS T06
FROM yourTable
```